# Support for Locales(tn-ph) and (hmn-cn) in java

Tags: java, java-8, locale

How can we support the locales for Tagalog(tl-ph) and Hmong(hmn-CN) in java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) to codes of locale in java by oracle. I can see that for  `Tagalog` it's `tgl` & for `Hmong` it's `hmn`.

```
Locale tagalogLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("tgl").setRegion("CA").build();
Locale hmongLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("hmn").setRegion("CA").build();
```

`CA` is the country name for `Canada` for any other countries, you can get the codes from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html)